# Recursive Minimax Function returns None instead of optimal score

Tags: python, search, artificial-intelligence, tic-tac-toe, minimax

I'm simply working on a Minimax algorithm that can play TicTacToe, For some reason the max_value and min_value functions occasionally return None.

```
def player(board):
    if Terminal(board) != False:
        return None
    else:
        if turn(board) == "X":
            value,move = max_value(board)
            return move
        else:
            value,move = min_value(board)
            return move
        
def max_value(board):
    if Terminal(board) != False:
        return Utility(board),None
    else:
        v = -1000
        move = None
        for action in Actions(board):
            aux,act = min_value(Result(board,action))
            print(aux)
            if aux > v:
                v = aux
                move = action
                if v == 1:
                    return v,move
        return v,move

def min_value(board):
    if Terminal(board) != False:
        return Utility(board),None
    else:
        v = 1000
        move = None
        for action in Actions(board):
            aux,act = max_value(Result(board,action))
            print(aux)
            if aux < v:
                v = aux
                move = action
                if v == -1:
                    return v,move
        return v,move
```

Terminal returns state of the game,Action returns possible moves and result creates a board given an action.

The error I get is `'>' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'int'` pops up for `if aux < v:` and `if aux > v:`
When I print aux, it occasionally appears as `None`.
Thanks.

Comment: What does `Utility(board)` do?  It looks like that returns `None` sometimes, and you don't have any code that translates that into a numeric value for the rest of your function to deal with.

Comment: If you use a debugger, if you look at the call stack that led up to that error happening, you should be able to use that, along with the state of the variables at the time of the crash, to trace the source of the issue. Obviously, `aux` is being returned as `None` by `max_value` or `min_value`, but without knowing the definition of `Terminal(board)` or `Utility(board)`, it's hard to say what could be happening. You should post a [mre].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you have shared is fine.

The error message indicates that `Utility` returns `None` when you call it. This should not happen. `Utility` should **always** return an integer when the game is over, and looking at your code it should return -1, 0 or 1.

There is also the possibility that `Utility` returns None when the game is not over, but that `Terminal` has a bug such that it returns something else than `False` even when the game is not over.

Here is an implementation of the functions `Terminal` and `Utility` that do not produce the error you got, but make it work as expected.

In fact, I added all missing functions based on a board representation that is a string of 9 characters, and a game loop so you can play against the minimax algorithm:

```
import re

def Utility(board):
    m = re.findall(r"([XO])(?:\1\1(?:...)*$|..\1..\1|...\1...\1|.\1.\1..$)", board)
    return -1 if "O" in m else len(m)
    
def Terminal(board):
    return "O X"[Utility(board)+1].strip() or not board.count(".") and "draw"

def turn(board):
    return "OX"[board.count(".") % 2]

def Actions(board):
    return (i for i in range(9) if board[i] == ".")

def Result(board, action):
    return board[:action] + turn(board) + board[action+1:]

board = "." * 9
while True:  # Interactive game between human and minimax
    print(f"{board[:3]}\n{board[3:6]}\n{board[6:]}")
    winner = Terminal(board)
    if winner:
        print(f"Winner: {winner}")
        break
    if turn(board) == "X":
        action = int(input("Your move (0..8)? "))
        if board[action] != ".":
            print("Invalid move. Try again.")
            continue
    else:
        action = player(board)
        print("minimax chooses", action)
    board = Result(board, action)
```

Comment: yes, the problem was with my Utility function. I had overlooked some changes that I had made earlier. Thank you.